# Route .nz domain to elastic beanstalk (can't use Route 53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, domain-name

I've got a website hosted on elastic beanstalk and a .nz domain on [www.sitehost.com](http://www.sitehost.com).

I need to route the domain to the website. All the documentation I'm seeing tells me to transfer the domain to Route 53... but you can't use .nz domains with Route 53.

I've had a look at setting up DNS records on my current domain host but I'm not 100% which records/information need to be added. Is it as simple as adding DNS records? Or can you only route elastic beanstalk websites through Route 53 and do I need to take my website off AWS and host somewhere else??

Appreciate any advice!

Cheers,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it as simple as adding DNS records?

Depends on the capabilities given to you by sitehost and what is your domain. If you want to point subdomain (e.g. [www.mysite.nz](http://www.mysite.nz)) to EB, just use CNAME record. If you want to point root domain (e.g mysite.nz) CNAME can't be used, and you may need to contact sitehost if they have any special/custom records for root domains.

> Or can you only route elastic beanstalk websites through Route 53 and do I need to take my website off AWS and host somewhere else??

You can host it on AWS. But if the sitehost does not allow you to create CNAME or other records, then you can setup Route53 as your DNS service. This is different then migrating a domain. Your domain is still in sitehost, but all its records are managed by R53. This requires you to setup [NS records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-in-use.html#migrate-dns-change-name-servers-with-provider) in sitehost. But again, it depends if sitehost allows you to do it.